Derivation of transfer matrices for accelerator elements
I am trying to derive the transfer matrices for different elements in particle accelerators. For simplicity, let's consider the drift space. The Hamiltonian in the standard Frenet-Serret coordinates is given as:
$$
H = \frac{\delta}{\beta_0} - \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\beta_0} + \delta\right)^2 - p_x^2 - p_y^2 - \frac{1}{\beta_0^2 \gamma_0^2}}
$$
Where:

$ \delta$ is the fractional momentum deviation.
$\beta_0 $ and $\gamma_0 $ are the relativistic parameters of the reference particle.
$ p_x $ and $ p_y$ are the transverse momentum components.

Symplectic Condition and Hamiltonian Expansion
To ensure that the transfer matrix remains symplectic (i.e., preserving the phase space volume), the Hamiltonian is typically expanded to second order in the dynamical variables. This yields:
$$
H \approx \frac{1}{2} p_x^2 + \frac{1}{2} p_y^2 + \frac{\delta^2}{2 \beta_0^2 \gamma_0^2}
$$
However, this step is never explicitly derived in any reference text I have come across, and for some reason I cannot seem to do it, as I usually end up with something extremely complicated, or when evaluating the terms they are all zero. I am trying to do a Taylor expansion around $\delta, p_x, p_y = 0$. At this point I can't tell if I suck at differentiating and evaluating terms (I defo do), or if I am doing something fundamentally wrong.
If anyone has any suggestions on how to approach this derivation or has a written derivation for this problem, please let me know!
